# Form POST returns 302 from within Joomla, works great outside

Tags: forms, post, joomla, http-status-code-302, google-checkout

I have a form that submit a shopping cart to Google Checkout. The form works great on it's own, but when I put it inside of Joomla (using a content-type of wrapper), Google Checkout throws a 302, and the form page is loaded again.

As I was writing this, I then decided to see what happens from the static form, outside of Joomla. It took gets a 302, but Google Checkout loads.

If I go directly to the request url listed in the resource inspector (using chrome for this), I get an error:

```
Oops!
We were unable to process your request.
```

That happens on both the Joomla wrapped form and the stand alone.

However, both forms receive response headers, with a Location url that goes to Google Checkout, and in fact loads the proper data.

Any ideas how to get this working inside of Joomla? Or what I might be doing wrong?

I don't know this stuff well enough to explain myself too well, so if you have a clarifying question, I'd be more than happy to provide as much info as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in fact that the form was trying to redirect the entire page from inside an i-frame. Brought the form out into a component and it works fine.